# How do I show all items (reset filters) if I click "Show All"? This is just a practice/sample app. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    List<Map<String, String>> get _filteredItems {
      if (_selectedCategoryIndex == 0) {
      return _items;
     } else {
      return _items
          .where((item) =>
              item['category'] == _categories[_selectedCategoryIndex - 1])
          .toList();
     }
    }
```

Do I need to change something here or on the ontap below:

```
    return ListTile(
                  title: Text(category),
                  tileColor: index + 1 == _selectedCategoryIndex
                      ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3)
                      : null,
                  onTap: () => _selectCategory(index + 1),
                );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.